# Is it possible to Add Claims after PostAuthenticateRequest event executes?

Tags: asp.net, security, wif, claims-based-identity

I am dealing with this weird situation. When the user logs in, I am only able to set the name claim for the ClaimsIdentity. Then the user selects a certain clinic from a list. Based on the selection I set their role claim(s). However what I've noticed is ASP.NET Url Authorization simply ignores these role claims because they werent setup in the PostAuthenticateRequest. Is there any other event I can hook into to set these additional claims?

Comment: What do you do to "set" them?

Comment: I set the role claims at the time the user selects a clinic from the list. Which happens in DataGrid.ItemCommand Event

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Oh sorry I read your your question as where do I set them. I have a ClaimsAuthenticationManager that modifies the incoming principle identity and adds the role claims

Comment: on every request? At which stage? Are they persisted in the authentication session (SAM)?

Comment: I have two ClaimsAuthenticationManager. Authorize method gets called on every request. One of them in PostAuthenticationRequest (sets name claim) the other in the Page_Load event of where the clinic gets selected (sets role claim). No SAM

Comment: Well - then use the SAM. Obviously Page_Load is too late.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with this approach.

1. Store Clinic ID to regular Session
2. Implement **ClaimsAuthenticationManager** of your own which will check
   for that Session entry, and if one exists, hydrate incoming
       ClaimsIdentity with new Role claims

Once Clinic is selected, you redirect user to another controller/action, and on the next request ClaimsAuthenticationManager will jump in and modify identity with new claims thus providing roles to user.

Comment: This is the approach I thought of doing next. My question is do I have to set the claims in PostAuthenticateRequest? When I add the claims in Page_Load event they get ignored by Url Auth module.

Comment: Unfortunately Session is not available in AuthenticateRequest or PostAuthenticateRequest

Comment: You don't want to use Session.

Comment: What would u recommend using?